# Get monthly count of received mails in list of inboxes

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

I am trying to get a monthly report of received e-mails from a list of e-mail-addresses. I want to export the results to a .csv and if possible send the csv automatically via e-mail to another address.

This is my approach in the exchange-management-shell looks like this but isn't creating any data in the .csv

```
    $mail = @("mymail@mydomain.com","another@mydomain.com")
$(foreach ($name in $mail)
{
    $startofmonth = Get-Date -format MM/dd/yyyy -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0
    $endofmonth = ((Get-Date -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1))
    $endofmonth = "{0:MM/dd/yy}" -f [datetime]$endofmonth

    $results = (Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize unlimited -recipients $name -Start $startofmonth -End $endofmonth -EventId RECEIVE).count
    $results
}) | Export-CSV -path \\mymachine\c$\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

How do I get the data that I want like this in the .csv:

> mailaddress | count(received mails) | timeframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom object for each result and return that to an array `$output`. Then convert the array into a `CSV` format and output it to a file.

```
$mail = @("mymail@mydomain.com","another@mydomain.com")
$startofmonth = Get-Date -format MM/dd/yyyy -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0
$endofmonth = ((Get-Date -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1))
$endofmonth = "{0:MM/dd/yy}" -f [datetime]$endofmonth

[Array]$output = foreach ($name in $mail) {

    $results = (Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize unlimited -recipients $name -Start $startofmonth -End $endofmonth -EventId RECEIVE).count

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name=$name;
        Received=$results;
        StartTime=$startofmonth;
        EndTime=$endofmonth;
    }
}

$output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -FilePath \\mymachine\c$\output.csv -Append
```

This will return a `CSV` file that looks like this:

```
"Name","Received","StartTime","EndTime"
"mymail@mydomain.com","222","10/01/2016","10/31/16"
"another@mydomain.com","340","10/01/2016","10/31/16"
```

Comment: how would i add a row with the timespan?

Comment: @Zoba I have updated my answer to show the timespan in the CSV file.

Comment: @Zoba Update: taken the calculation of time variables out of the loop to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
 $mails = ("mymail@mydomain.com","another@mydomain.com")
 $startofmonth = Get-Date -format MM/dd/yyyy -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0
 $endofmonth = ((Get-Date -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1))
 $endofmonth = "{0:MM/dd/yy}" -f [datetime]$endofmonth


 Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start $startofmonth -End  $endofmonth -EventId RECEIVE | where{$_.Recipients -in   $mails} | select- object  Timestamp,SourceContext,Source,EventId,MessageSubject,Sender, {$_.Recipients} | 
group-object -property Timestamp |
export-csv C:\temp\MessageTrackingLogResults.csv
```

Comment: this would give me the messages itself - I'm only interested in the count of the mails per month. To track how much was sent to each specific account.

Comment: there is a space too much between select- and object. Also the result would be: #TYPE Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo
"Values","Count","Group","Name"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","1","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","04.10.2016 13:20:34"